# Kentico Forgot Password Link Expired Issue

Tags: email, kentico

I am looking into what is probably a common marketing email issue. If our Kentico users forget their password, they go through the reset password process.

What is happening we think is their organization's email filters are scanning the email and bot-clicking the reset link for security reasons which then results in an expired link when the user goes to reset their pass.

What can we put in place to not expire the link if a bot follows the link for 1 time expiration? Does Kentico have anything out of the box for this or would this require custom code to not expire the link if clicked once and expire the link after 24 hours. That to me seems like it would enter risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing the link to be used more than once would be a security risk. You need to add e.g. some exceptions in the filtering software to not to check links from your site. Or, not to use the link confirmation for resetting passwords. There are no settings for this in Kentico as it is more the filtering software setup - Kentico cannot decide whether it is the real user, attacker or just a bot (even bots can be evil sometimes).